# Count occurrences of a list of ip in a text file

Tags: powershell, file, count

I need to count occurrences in file text of a list ip.

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
```

I've tried:

`Get-Content "C:\listip.txt" | Select-String -Pattern '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$' | measure`

But I received the total and not the sum of each occurrence. On linux I would have simply used uniq -c

Comment: Why not use Group-Object?

Comment: Are you sure you need the regex? If every line contains a single valid IP, then just: Get-Content "C:\listip.txt" | Group -NoElement

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon), simply pipe into [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
Get-Content "c:\listip.txt" | 
    Select-String -Pattern '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$' | 
    Group-Object -NoElement | 
    Select-Object Count, @{ n='IP'; e='Name' }
```

**Output:**

```text
Count IP
----- --
    4 1.1.1.1
    9 8.8.8.8
```

The parameter `-NoElement` removes the `Group` property that is output by default by `Group-Object`, but is not needed for counting only.

I've added `Select-Object` to rename the `Name` property to `IP`, using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) .

If you'd like to correctly sort the unique IPs (i. e. not string sort, but number by number), you might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72409315/7571258).

Comment: Use NoElement? Good idea.

Comment: @jimhark Thanks! I've already added it after reading your 1st comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-group-integers-by-odds-and-evens) can be using a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Get-Content C:\listip.txt | & {
    begin { $out = @{} }
    process { $out[$_.Trim()] += 1 }
    end { $out }
}
```

Output from the *anonymous function* would be:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1.1.1.1                        4
8.8.8.8                        9
```

If you want to filter or target **only the lines that match your pattern**, you can add an `if` condition and use the [Matching Operator `-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators):

```
Get-Content C:\listip.txt | & {
    begin { $out = @{} }
    process {
        # if the line matches this pattern there is for sure no need to `.Trim()`
        if($_ -match '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$') {
            $out[$_] += 1
        }
    }
    end { $out }
}
```